# PHP / JS image creation

Tags: php, javascript, gd2

I'm wondering if this is possible: user uploads a picture which is then presented to him in the browser. The image is placed inside a div that has predefined image as background. User can drag and drop his uploaded image inside the boundaries of this div.

It would be something along the lines of uploading a pic of yourself and then positioning it against a background of a tropical beach. User then clicks ok and has the option to download the image.

I have the upload and JS drag & drop covered. I'm just wondering: **is it the possible to create a new image on the server that exists of the back - and foreground image?** So basically an image would have to be created from the contents of the specified DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the functions of GD, you may also want to check out imageMagick

Comment: Any idea which GD functions can help me do this?